# Microsoft Exchange calendar not updating on android

Tags: calendar, exchange

I can not get calendar to work properly: only original appointment times are shown, when an appointment is moved / cancelled, the change is not reflected.

I've a Samsung A52 phone with latest version of Android, We use Microsoft Exchange (Office 365) e-mail in our organization.

I've tried Outlook, Gmail, Samsung calendar; with or without installing Intune Company Portal - the issue is always the same - events are downloaded to my phone, but changes are not reflected.

Everything else (mails, contacts, downloading new calendar items) works well with all tried solutions.

The issue exists since several months now.

Current workaround is to check my calendar only on the website of outlook

Comment: Do emails sync normally?

Comment: Yes, emails are OK, as well as contacts.

Comment: Maybe this [suggestion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-sync-outlook-calendar-with-android-calendar/babd0e50-6e78-4b9c-b5fa-593c045c3bfe) might be helpful (if for whatever reason the toggle to sync is off)